# Multiple sticky headers

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there another way I can get multiple sticky headers to stack under each other than setting the top offset as the height of the previous sticky headers?

In the code snippet if I set `top: 50px` in `.inner-header` it works fine but I am looking for some other solution where I don't need to touch `.inner-header` styles

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
}

.section {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.inner-header {
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Main sticky header
  </div>
  <div class="content"> 
    <div class="section">
      <div class="inner-header">
        Section sticky header
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px
}

.header {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
}

.section {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.inner-header {
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 2.4rem;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Main sticky header
  </div>
  <div class="content"> 
    <div class="section">
      <div class="inner-header">
        Section sticky header
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am looking for a way where I don't need to touch `.inner-header`  styles

Comment: @Kremdas Changing the question after having received an answer is not a good etiquette.